# Read csv Pandas spaces multiples

Tags: python, pandas

[image]

I have a very similar dataset in csv file with two column,

For Example:
*In first row and first column*
Item:"Betarraga paquete 5 unidades"

*In first row and second column*
qty:1

```
Item    qty
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    2
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
CANASTA PEQUEÑA 1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   2
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 3
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
```

II should like to read with pandas, but using:

```
     df1 = pd.read_csv(r'pedidos4.csv',sep='\s+',encoding='utf-8',error_bad_lines=False)
```

This only returns 2 column but first word in the first column input as rowname

[image]

```
  df.shape
  (15, 2)
```

Comment: And if you use `sep='\t'`?

Comment: return only one column

Comment: check my updated answer with the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to read the exact text block you have posted as 2 columns. Please try using `sep='\s\s+'`

After that, you can write a function that takes in a row, checks if `qty` is `null`, fixes the `qty` column and the `Item` column and returns the row. Then you can apply it over the `df` over `axis=1`

```
Item    qty
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    2
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
CANASTA PEQUEÑA 1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   2
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 3
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
```

```
df = pd.read_clipboard('\s\s+')

#Then use fix to fix the qty values

def fix(row):
    if pd.isnull(row['qty']):
        row['qty']=row['Item'][-1:]
        row['Item']=row['Item'][:-1].strip()
    return row

fixed_df = df.apply(fix, axis=1)
print(fixed_df)
```

```
                            Item qty
0   Betarraga paquete 5 unidades   1
1   Betarraga paquete 5 unidades   2
2   Betarraga paquete 5 unidades   1
3   Betarraga paquete 5 unidades   1
4               CANASTA PEQUEÑA    1
5      Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
6      Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   2
7      Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
8           Cebollin atado de 3    2
9           Cebollin atado de 3    2
10          Cebollin atado de 3    3
11          Cebollin atado de 3    1
12          Cebollin atado de 3    1
13          Cebollin atado de 3    1
14          Cebollin atado de 3    1
```

Comment: In row 4, 8, 9, 10,11,12,13 and 14 in qty, isn't NaN,  the last number is qty

Comment: right, that is because some of your lines have multiple spaces and others have single spaces. You can fix that with a apply function.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the last element of each line to be column2, and the rest in column 1. So you may have to do it manually because the amount of whitespace is inconsistent for different rows and I do not think the standard `read_csv` approach is easy to make work. So here is an alternative

This is our data

```
file = StringIO(
"""Item    qty
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    2
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
Betarraga paquete 5 unidades    1
CANASTA PEQUEÑA 1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   2
Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades   1
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 2
Cebollin atado de 3 3
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
Cebollin atado de 3 1
""")

#If 'myfile.txt' is where this data is, you should replace the above with
# file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
```

Then we read `file` line by line, split the line at white space, use the last token as column 2 and the rest as column1, and stick in a dataframe

```
col1 = []
col2 = []
for line in file:
    tokens = line.split()
    c1 = ' '.join(tokens[:-1])
    c2 = tokens[-1]
    col1.append(c1)
    col2.append(c2)

df = pd.DataFrame({col1[0] : col1[1:], col2[0] : col2[1:]})
df['qty'] = df['qty'].astype(int)
df
```

produces

```
    Item                            qty
--  ----------------------------  -----
 0  Betarraga paquete 5 unidades      1
 1  Betarraga paquete 5 unidades      2
 2  Betarraga paquete 5 unidades      1
 3  Betarraga paquete 5 unidades      1
 4  CANASTA PEQUEÑA                   1
 5  Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades         1
 6  Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades         2
 7  Cebolla Nueva 20 unidades         1
 8  Cebollin atado de 3               2
 9  Cebollin atado de 3               2
10  Cebollin atado de 3               3
11  Cebollin atado de 3               1
12  Cebollin atado de 3               1
13  Cebollin atado de 3               1
14  Cebollin atado de 3               1
```